# Android Open GL not drawing square

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have been following the Android Developer Open GL tutorial and iv just trying to draw a square in my own program as am starting to rewrite my android game in Open GL as opposed to using the Canvas class. I have encountered a problem where it wont draw the square that i am trying to draw but it will color the background.

I am trying to draw the GLSquareEntity class which is extended from the GLEntity class, below is the code

GLSquareEntity Class:

```
public class GLSquareEntity extends GLEntity
{

    public GLSquareEntity() 
    {
        super();

        cords = new float[] {
                -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
                 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
                 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

        CORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;

        drawOrder = new short[] { 0, 1, 2, 0 , 2, 3 };

        // Initlise the class
        setup();
    }

}
```

GLEntity Class:

```
public class GLEntity 
{
    protected final String TAG = "GLENTITY";

    // Shaders
    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
            "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
            "void main() {" +
            "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
            "}";

    // Open GL Variables
    protected FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    protected ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    protected short[] drawOrder;
    protected int CORDS_PER_VERTEX;
    protected int vertexStride;
    protected int  vertexCount;
    protected float[] cords; 

    // Just unill i can get an image to display
    protected float[] color = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};

    protected int program;
    protected int positionHandle;
    protected int colorHandle;

    public GLEntity()
    {

    }

    protected void setup()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "GLEntity Setup");

        vertexStride = CORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
        vertexCount = cords.length / CORDS_PER_VERTEX;

        // Initilise buffer for vertex cordernats
        ByteBuffer vbuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(cords.length * 4);
        vbuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = vbuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(cords);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // Initilise buffer for the draw list
        ByteBuffer dlbuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2);
        dlbuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        drawListBuffer = dlbuffer.asShortBuffer();
        drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
        drawListBuffer.position(0);

        // Set up the shaders

        int vertexShader = OpenGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = OpenGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
}    

    public void draw()
    {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Drawing GL Entity");
        // Select shader program to use
        GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

        positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

        // Prepar the data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, CORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // Prepare and set the color
        colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "vColor");
        GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        //GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertexCount);
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    }

}
```

The next classes are the GLSurfaceView class and the GLRenderer class

GLSurfaceView Class:

```
public class OpenGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView 
{

    public OpenGLSurfaceView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);

        // Set to OpenGL ES 2
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        // Set the renderer for drawing
        //OpenGLRenderer glRenderer = ;
        setRenderer( new OpenGLRenderer() );

        // Set to only rerender when function called
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

}
```

OpenGLRenderer Class:

```
public class OpenGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer 
{
    GLPlayer player;

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) 
    {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        player.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) 
    {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) 
    {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        player = new GLPlayer();

    }

    public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode)
    {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        return shader;
    }

}
```

Any help figuring out what the problem is would be much appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: If the square you are trying to draw is colouring the background it might be it simply takes the whole screen being too large. Anyway where do you set uMVPMatrix? You should probably at least set some matrix like "ortho" using (-1, 1, -viewHeight/viewWidth, viewHeight/viewWidth...) or your square will be a rectangle (unless your view is a square).

Comment: The color of the square and the background is different so i know that the square isnt being drawn. also i am going that later but for now i am just trying to get the drawing to work

Comment: Still the square is probably not being drawn because of that matrix. If nothing else try removing it from the shader before you implement it or just set it to identity or something. If you did not set any parameter to that matrix it is probably multiplying your vertices with some garbage values or all zeros!

Comment: Not setting the "uMVPMatrix" uniform matrix will probably cause uMVPMatrix to be a 0 matrix in the shader which in turn make all your geometry set to (0, 0, 0) from the vertex shader. So nothing can be drawn this way.